# Cancel / Abort Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, network-programming, task

Please take a look at the following code

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();    

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Socket serverSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Helper.PORT));
        serverSocket.Listen(0);

        while(true)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();

            Client client = new Client(clientSocket);

            Task t = new Task(delegate { client.Handle(); });
            t.Start();
            tasks.Add(t);
        }
    }

Client.Handle():

while (true)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    clientSocket.Recieve(buffer);
    //Do Something...
}
```

Is there any way to cancel / abort the task when there are more than 10 Tasks in the List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cancel a task in c#, you have to add a `CancellationTokenSource` that you can call to cancel the task

It would look something along the lines of

```cs
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task t = new Task(() => TaskRun(), cts.Token);
t.Start();
cts.Cancel();
```

In your example it would more-or-less be like:

```
// ...

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
while(true)
{
  Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
  Client client = new Client(clientSocket);
  Task t = new Task(() => client.Handle(), cts.Token);
  t.Start();
  tasks.Add(t);

  if(tasks.Count() >= 10) cts.Cancel();
}

// ...
```

But I don't quite understand your code. You have multiple infinite loops, including an infinite loop inside of another loop. Once your code gets to the part for `Socket clientSocket...` it will never get out of that loop. In addition, cancelling all the tasks in your `List<Task>` won't remove those tasks and you'll eventually run out of memory.

If you are only hoping for 10 tasks you might be better of with a set task array like `Task[] tasks = new Task[10];` and then when you fill up the array, exit out of the inner loop -- this would also allow you to use a for/foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The outer loop listens for incoming connections and the inner loop handles these connections.